# How to associate the contents of an XML file into an org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem in Java

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

Currently I'm displaying the contents of an XML file in an Editor (in 2 forms ) containing 2 TabItems say UI and XML Tabs .

One TabItem (UI Tab) is responsible to display the structure of the XML file in a Tree View structure (rendering the XML contents in the form of Tree view ) and the other one (XML Tab) should be able to display the xml file contents itself.

But when trying to implement the latter (XML Tab), I'm facing some problems.

The problem is i couldn't able to associate an XML file to an org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem.

Any idea of achieving this will be highly appreciated !

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'associate'. You can use JFace `TextViewer` or SWT `StyledText` or `Text` as a control in the `TabItem` to show the file contents.

Comment: @greg-449: By 'associate' ,  I mean the displaying the contents of an xml file into a TabItem.

Comment: @greg-449: Any link could you suggest (for deploying an StyledText or Text control in TabItem) so that I may get an idea on how to proceed with this. 

Thank You so much for your Reply!

Comment: Is this just an SWT application or is it an Eclipse plugin? For a plugin you should probably be using `FormEditor` or `MultiPageEditorPart` to manage multiple pages.

Comment: @greg-449: It is an Eclipse plugin . Im using MultiPageEditorPart for displaying the UI part.  Any Default Editor exists for displaying the XML file ??

Comment: MultiPageEditorPart doesn't use TabItem, in any case you should be calling `addPage`. Eclipse WST has a XML editor. One of the examples available when you use 'New > Project.. > Plug-in Project' creates a multiple page editor with a basic text editor.

Comment: @greg-449: You are correct in stating to use MultiPageEditorPart for managing multiple pages. This is what I was using and in order to add another page using the method "addPage(editor, getEditorInput());" what EDITOR i should use ?? Any default exists or I should create a new one ?

Comment: @greg-449: I need a XML Editor instance for passing it as an input to the addPage method , Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: As I have already said you might be able to use the Eclipse WST XML editor - but I don't know anything about using this. Otherwise look at the example multiple page editor.

Comment: @greg-449: Thank You Greg for your valuable information.. I will check it out.

Comment: Im getting a Null Pointer Exception when trying to add the default XML Editor view as an addtional page to my MultiPageEditor. Any suggestions on how to display the xml contents in a multipage editor ??